# How can I get the active dowloands in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to get the active downloads of a page? Or at least, if there are any downloads?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Are you asking how you can view them, or use that info with writing a extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Chrome extension API to access downloads, but it is not yet widely available:

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads.html

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl+J for windows in chrome to see current downloads? It will show all downloads including old downloads though..

Cmd + shift + J for mac